# avplayer is not playing the URL

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using avplayer for play audio url, but it is not working, I don't know where i am wrong

```
NSString *radioURL = @"https://www.example.com";

radioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:radioURL]] ;
// [radioPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
NSLog(@"radio player %@",radioPlayer.currentItem);
[radioPlayer play];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think URL must have an Extension e.g https://example.com/myfile.mp3

Comment: radioURL is not a valid file that can be played.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but url is working if i play it in browser or anywhere else.

Comment: show us the real URL. Not the `example.com`

Comment: with AVplayer check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850447/how-to-get-audio-to-play-from-an-online-url-on-iphone else you can use AVAudioPlayer

Comment: get response "AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay", but audio didn't play

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I strongly recommended the code below to play radio streaming: please take a look also [AVPlayer_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html)

```
 -(void)Play{
        NSString *radioURL = @"https://www.example.com"; //this url must valid 
        AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:radioURL]];
        self.songPlayer = player;    //self.songPlayer is a globle object of avplayer
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[songPlayer currentItem]];
        [self.songPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

        if (object == songPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
            if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
                NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

            } else if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
                NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
                [self.songPlayer play];


            } else if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
                NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

            }
        }
    }

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

     //  code here to play next sound file

    }
```

Ref link is - [Streaming mp3 audio with AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131177/streaming-mp3-audio-with-avplayer)

Comment: get response AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay, but audio didn't play :(

Comment: where did you testing in device or simulator? if device then plz check iphone not silent mode

Comment: can you please share a url of streaming.

Comment: @NitinGohel, above code does not work for me.iPhone is not silent mode.any idea?

Comment: what should i have to do for https?

Comment: you need to set  App Transport Security Settings for

Comment: @NitinGohel please give me a solutaion

Comment: @  Prachi Rajput did you get solution yet, in my case I get response AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay, but audio didn't play. Please reply ASAP. thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and just realized that I wasn't **retaining** the player (using ARC)! So it gets deallocated and stop playing immediately after start.

You need to make sure that you have a strong property **radioPlayer** and use **self.radioPlayer** instead of radioPlayer.

Comment: @ Borzh, I did same as you tolad. In my case I get response AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay, but audio didn't play. Please reply ASAP. thanks

Comment: @Monu singh, probably you have some other problem, I just told the problem I had myself.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing good but your method need to correct on one place.Check using the below method:

```
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:radioURL];
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];
self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
self.audioPlayer.volume=1.0;
[self.audioPlayer autorelease];
[self.audioPlayer Play];
```

and add proper delegate methods for AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: No need to Convert to NSData

Answer (score -1):

Make Sure URL is `AddingPercentEscapes`.

```
NSURL *audioURL = // Your Url;
NSString *encodedString = [@"Your Url" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:encodedString]
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
player play];
```

Comment: weird ... where did that prepareToPlay comefrom? in AVPlayer? can't seem to find it on the .h source io8 is that removed?

Comment: It's probably wrong since its an method on AVAudioPlayer, not AVPlayer

Answer (score -1):

Did you forgot to set the attribute `App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads (Yes)`?

[image: App Transport Security Settings]