# AVAudioPlayer not playing audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

When I tap on an image view, I am trying to play music. When I run the following code, the music doesn't play. The music is an .m4a:

.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface ChooseViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

.m

```
- (void)imageTaped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // 
    self.songURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a1745.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/011/Music6/v4/91/d0/45/91d0451d-c2cd-911a-491e-4f51c02e6b38/mzaf_4642375274280516284.plus.aac.p.m4a"];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.songURL
                                                                       error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVAudioPlayer not playing any sound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016765/avaudioplayer-not-playing-any-sound)

Comment: As you can see by my code, I tried that solution, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you Try this code

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound.mp3", resourcePath];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error = nil;

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                                    error:&error];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: I need to get the url from online, not stored on the device or project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850447/how-to-get-audio-to-play-from-an-online-url-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this line right after setting the URL:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mp3URL];
```